# dataframe slicing with loc

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

```
     I have a datframe,df

                2.3.6     16.3.9   9.2.7  43.5.2   4.5.6   45.2.1
August            2         1       8       3        10      3
September         7         0       7       3        5       4
October           1         2       5       3        2       2
November          0         0       8       9        0       3
```

I want a new dataframe to just keep the first 2 columns

I used the following code:

```
df2=df.loc[:, df['16.3.9']]
print (df2)
```

KeyError: 'None of [ \nSeptember    2.0\nOctober      2.0\nNovember     0.0\nName: 16.3.9, dtype: float64] are in the [columns]'

Or perhaps is there a way I can slice the dataframe,df into 1 figure with different subplots that have 2 columns each?

Comment: after trying your code, I got this:
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [2] of <class 'int'>

Comment: You are mixing different indexing methods here. Either use `df.iloc[:,:2]` or `df.loc[:,["2.3.6","16.3.9"]]` or `df[["2.3.6","16.3.9"]]` to select the first two columns.

Comment: thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest  Is there a way I can slice the dataframe,df into 1 figure with different subplots that have 2 columns each?

Comment: Yes, but that question has also already been asked somewhere. Please look for respecive SO question first.